# I am trying to solve a non-linear equation. In the matlab program, I'm stuck up.

Tags: matlab, programming

One of the problems could be that, I want a matrix of order 3*3 but the output is 4*4, with first row and first column consisting of zeros. Can someone help !

n=5; m=5; T=1;
for i=2:n-1
for q=2:m-1
uexact(i,q,T)=exp(i+q-3*T);

```
end
```

end

uexact =

```
     0         0         0         0
     0    2.7183    7.3891   20.0855
     0    7.3891   20.0855   54.5982
     0   20.0855   54.5982  148.4132
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: We're mathematicians.  We're _all_ stuck up.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$uexact(i-1,q-1,T)=exp(i+q-3*T);$

instead.
Even though your original code does only assign values to columns 2-5 and rows 2-5, Matlab automatically assumes that there must be a column 1 and row 1 to which it assigns 0 as a default value.

Comment: getting a 4*4 matrix with this modification

Comment: Run $clear\ all$ first

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I have some other error now, but this one got better.

Comment: Great. But please post the next programming question not to math.stackexchange. there are dedicated forums for programming in there stackexchange forum family, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can you please tell how can i write [ b11 b12 0 0; b21 b22 0 0; 0 0 b11 b12; 0 0 b21 b22][u11 u21 u12 u22] into [b11 b12 0 0; 0 0 b11 b12; b21 b22 0 0; 0 0 b21 b22][u11 u12 u21 u22]? Actually i am getting the second matrix but i want to get first system.. Is there any way please!

Comment: @ppratiikshaa I don't really understand what you want to say, but it sounds like as if you pose a new question. So, what about posting it in a new thread? It would be best to post this thread in a programming forum, as already stated